# Binary numbers to MLT-3

Tags: c, networking

I need to write a C program that has a binary number on input and the same number in MLT-3 code on output (voltages +, 0, - accordingly). The voltages only change at '1', at '0' they are unchanged:

```
10010111
+++00-0+
```

How do I 'roll' these values?

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char states[4] = { '+', '0', '-', '0' };
    int index = 3;
    int b = 0x97;         // OP example
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<8; i++) {
        if (b & 0x80)
            index = (index + 1) % 4;
        printf ("%c", states[index]);
        b <<= 1;
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Program output

```
+++00-0+
```

Answer (score 0):

A basic flow indicated by the code.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
    int direction = 1;//1: upto, -1: downto
    int state = 0;
    char *seq = "10010111";
    while(*seq){
        if(*seq == '1'){
            state += direction;
            if(state == 1 || state == -1)
                direction = -direction;//reversal of direction
        }
        switch(state){//putchar("-0+"[state+1]);
        case 1: putchar('+');break;
        case 0: putchar('0');break;
        case -1: putchar('-');break;
        }
        ++seq;
    }
    return 0;
}
```